# Sum a Calculated Field in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, report, sum, grouping

I have a few fields, drawn from the query, which go into a dual-grouped report (grouped on Parent and Child). Within those groups are several fields which are counted together. These counts are then averaged into a "Total Parent-Child Average".

```
Parent1     PARENT COMPLIANCE: 45% <- (40% + 50% / 2)
      Child1
           TOTAL WITHIN CHILD: 50
           CONDITION 1       : 20%
           CONDITION 2       : 40%
           CONDITION 3       : 60% <- Implies 30 out of 50 compliant
           CHILD COMPLIANCE  : 40% <- (20% + 40% + 60% / 3)
      Child2
           TOTAL WITHIN CHILD: 20
           CONDITION 1       : 25%
           CONDITION 2       : 100%
           CONDITION 3       : 25% <- Implies 5 out of 20 compliant
           CHILD COMPLIANCE  : 50% <- (25% + 100% + 50% / 3)
```

Currently, the `PARENT COMPLIANCE` is in the header of the parent grouping. When I use something like `(ChildCompliance) / Count(Child)`, `Count(Child)` works as it should (counting the number of children to use as a divisor) but `(ChildCompliance)` does not produce a sum; it only grabs the number from Child1 (in this case 40%). Currently, `PARENT COMPLIANCE: 20%` is what I get (because it grabs 40% / 2).

I've tried `SUM(ChildCompliance)` in the Parent header, but it asks for ChildCompliance as a data field and not my calculated one (wants it in the query, which would be too laborious to do).

How can I sum my `CHILD COMPLIANCE` calculated fields in the Parent header?

**Clarification:**

Basically, it's come down to this: I need to be able to sum the CHILD COMPLIANCE values for all children within the Parent group. I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: I don't quite get you. Why are you not summing child compliance in the group footer?

Comment: Honestly, it's because I had not set a group footer for anything. It's the locations that the client requested.

Comment: Unless you want to make the whole thing far more complicated than it needs to be, sum and calculate in footers, group, report etc.

Comment: When I group in the footers, I cannot get the print view to properly reference the footers in my header. It works in report view (45% shows up), but in Print View I get 20% again. ??? No scripts are used on this report whatsoever.

Comment: Apparently I have that wrong, you can sum in headers as well ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/summing-in-reports-HA001122444.aspx). Reports are difficult in a forum :)

Comment: Surely there is a way for me to reference a sum of my ChildCompliance fields over the Parent group? As it is, I've needed to add a running sum to the footer of the child group, then change the location of my Parent Compliance to the Parent Footer in order for it to work consistently. This is a last resort for me..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14645/discussion-between-remou-and-stuckatwork)

Comment: Sum child divided by 6, not 2. I have an example.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208850 may be of interest.